External http link to a section of a Word document does not jump to particular section
There was a question asked previously, and the answer is valid. However, I found additional issue.
I have a document stored in company's SharePoint portal. I want to create external link to this document, which could jump to particular section of this document. I want this link to be shared with my colleagues within a company, use it in PTT presentation, or any other way.
For this, in the web version of Word I did this: right click on the heading I want link to jump to and select "Copy Link to Heading" (see screenshot).
Issue:
It seems that this link jumps to a section only when document opens straightly in Edit mode.
So for me it opens in Edit mode, since I am an author probably (see screenshot) and works well, and for others it simply opens the first page of the document (and document is opened in such mode where user must press button "Edit Document" in order to enable Edit mode, see screenshot).
Any ideas how to solve this issue?
By the way, I would want to avoid granting edit right to all the users. I would want it to work (to jump) for all users who can access (e.g. has read right) the file.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Clarified the description of my specific problem, added some details.
